# How to config babel-loader to make output code compatible with ie >= 9 in webpack 2?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

**Webpack Version:**
2.0

**Babel Core Version**:
6.24.1

**Babel Loader Version**:
7.0.0

**Please tell us about your environment:**
Ubuntu Server 14.04

**Current behavior:**
the output code is OK in chrome but not in IE >= 9. I check the code and find babel doesn't transmit code such as `for (let key of array) {}` for ie.

**Expected/desired behavior:**

I want the output code work both in ie >= 9 and chrome (latest).

**current webpack config:**

```
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ["env"],
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: I think you will gonna need babel-polyfill in order to support legacy browsers